# closing a web page with clicking a button

Tags: asp.net

I have a password changing page. I want to change password and close the page when user click the button. I tried following line at the end of the button click code but it does not work.

```
 this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Close", "window.close()", true);
```

Also I want to close parent page when clicked the button. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function info() {

        $.msgBox({
            title: "INFORMATION",
            content: "Password is changed successfuly, press OK to relogin ...",
            type: "info",
            afterClose: function () {
                window.close();
            },
            buttons: [{
                 value: "OK"                   
            }]
        });
    }
```

This method closes the pop up page after closing the message box. But in order to use this following plugins must be added to the page:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.msgBox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="Styles/msgBoxLight.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers will allow javascript to close only those windows that were opened with javascript.

If your change password page is not opened by javascript in a popup window, that code will not work.

Refer: [window.close](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.close)

> This method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened
>   by a script using the window.open method. If the window was not opened
>   by a script, the following error appears in the JavaScript Console:
>   Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.

Comment: You can write the script in code behind, but the window needs to be opened by script too.